# Github and Web deployment Issues on Heroku

Tags: python, django, github, heroku

I had deployed my django site on heroku.I have been facing some problems.When I add products or users in admin page,It just remains for one day and next day those products and users that i add it dissapears and another thing is how am I suppose to reflect those changes made in admin page to github repository.So I can clone it back to my computer for some purposes

Comment: Please post your code. We cannot help you without looking at your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to load intial data  you have to use  **fixtures** it's bascly a JSON file  that contain the data you want to upload to your model :

create a ** fixtures** folder inside your app then create  your JSON file inside that folder  :

exemple :

fixtures/mydata.json :

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Lennon"
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.person",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "first_name": "Paul",
      "last_name": "McCartney"
    }
  }
]
```

then in your comand line run :  manage.py loaddata mydata.json

for heroku  you have to provide more information  do you have any error when pushing your app or checkout your subscription /settings  in heroku

Comment: The things is i don't want to load inital data because it's not necessary.No,I don't have errors while pushing my app. Do you have any idea about how every changes made in database when you deploy your site on heroku how to reflect it back to Github. After deployment on heroku when I add users, blog posts it just remains for one day.

Comment: To apply changes in your model run: python manage.py makemigrations then: python manage.py migrate after pushing the app on your deployment server to insert data you have to do it manually or via fixtures that's the only two ways I know, for Heroku, you are limited by a certain number of rows in your database depending on your subscription so maybe you have to many data and Heroku delete automatically the new data to make space, you can contact them for more information